# Toggle images in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to toggle the images in knockout but failed, I searched a lot but unable to find the error.

Scenario is I am calling one function and inside that function I am toggling the image visible to true or false. you can refer the [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/fepojiriwu/edit?html,js,output)

HTML

```
<img class="flipButton"  data-bind="visible: !OpenWidgetObj.flipCard, click: function(){ OpenWidgetObj.flipProductCard();}, attr:{ src:'img/flipArrowRight.png' }" />
                <img class="flipButton"  data-bind="visible: OpenWidgetObj.flipCard, click: function(){ OpenWidgetObj.flipProductCard();}, attr:{ src:'img/flipArrowLeft.png' }" />
```

Here is javascript

```
OpenWidget=function(){
  self.flipCard= ko.observable(false);
  self.flipProductCard = function() {
        if( self.flipCard() === false){
            self.CardFlip(true);
        }
        else {
            self.CardFlip(false);   
        }
    };
};
OpenWidgetObj = new OpenWidget();
ko.applyBindings(OpenWidgetObj);
```

Comment: Where is `self.CardFlip` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you should change in your code:

1. you're changing the value of the inexistent property `CardFlip`. It should be `flipCard`. (That's a typo, I suppose)
2. the way you call the function from your code is not advisable. You should simply call it by name. Yous syntax is only necessary if you need to specify different parameters or something like that. Even show, you shuld move that to a function in your view model to call it simply by name
3. in your bindings, you have to refer directly to the observable members, i.e. `flipCard` instead of `OpenWidgetObj.flipCard`
4. if you need to negate a property value, you have to evaluate it, i.e. this: `!flipCard` will not work, but this `!flipCard()` will do.
5. You don't need to specify your `src` attribute using knockout, because you're not binding it to any view model property.

So, the HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="flipButton"  
    data-bind="visible: !flipCard(), click: flipProductCard"
    src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/abstract/6/" />
  <img class="flipButton"  
    data-bind="visible: flipCard, click: flipProductCard"
    src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/abstract/5/" />
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS, like this

```
var OpenWidget = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.flipCard= ko.observable(false);
  self.flipProductCard = function() {
    self.flipCard(!self.flipCard());
  };
};
OpenWidgetObj = new OpenWidget();
ko.applyBindings(OpenWidgetObj);
```

You can see it working in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/batusa/4/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

You should try this simplified version:

```
<img class="flipButton" data-bind="click: ToggleCard, attr:{ src: CardType === 'right' ? 'img/flipArrowRight.png' : 'img/flipArrowLeft.png'}" />

OpenWidget=function(){
    var self = this;
    self.CardType = ko.observable("right");

    self.ToggleCard = function() {
        self.CardType(self.CardType() === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left'); 
    }
};
OpenWidgetObj = new OpenWidget();
ko.applyBindings(OpenWidgetObj);
```